# How to use a runtime generated Sprite object as the icon of a List or Tree?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, tree, flex4, icons

I have been searching regards this question for months.

By default, the iconFunction of List and Tree return only Class as the icon, which is for embeded images or iconUtility kindly provided by this site http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=42. It works very well with pre-created images.

But what I really want is to accept a completely runtime generate sprite object, similar to what is done by Legend, with the color changes according to what the current status. I assume I could do something to make the ListBase to accept icon argument other than Class. Am I rite? or please kindly advise what I shall do.

Thank you very much!

Wildog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the icon for the tree item, I would create a custom item renderer using TreeItemRenderer as a starting point.  Then put whatever component you want to the left of the text and move the text to the right a bit.  Another advantage of this approach is that you can have your sprite change dynamically as the data that gets set to the item renderer changes.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Happy 2011! Thank you for answering. Actually I am currently using a grid and a list in a group, sitting side by side, to simulate the legend. May be I should really try using item renderer as you have suggested. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want to do, but you can turn your sprite into BitmapData easily enough (Which you can use to create a BitmapAsset)

e.g.

```
var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sprite.width, sprite.height);
bmp.draw(sprite);

var bmpasset:BitmapAsset = new BitmapAsset(bmp);
```

Comment: Happy New Year! Thank you for answering. 
Your method works great to convert sprite into BitmapAsset. But still, I couldn't use the return bitmapasset as the "iconfunction" of List, where the return should be Class. Should the bitmapasset method be used along with may be the iconutility to get it works? Thanks